# Getting drush to install missing dependencies automatically into libraries

Tags: drush

How to get drush to automatically install libraries ***or*** ignore dependencies?

Trying to automate enabling modules in batch with Drush

```
c:\2016\sites\all\modules>drush en views_slideshow_cycle -y
Module views_slideshow_cycle doesn't meet the requirements to be         [error]

enabled.
You need to install the jQuery cycle plugin. Create a directory in       [error]

sites/all/libraries called jquery.cycle, and then copy
jquery.cycle.all.min.js or jquery.cycle.all.js into it. You can find
the plugin at http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle. (Currently using jQuery
Cycle Library Library required for Views Slideshow Cycle)

c:\2016\sites\all\modules>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the module that handles "libraries" dependencies - not Drush. AFAIK you can't force Drush to ignore hook_requirements implemented by the module in (the install file). Some modules, for example Colorbox, provides a Drush command to download the missing libraries dependencies, but it's not automated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this Drupal 7, since you're installing to sites/all/modules. My guess is that you've installed Views Slideshow 7.x-3.1.

In Drupal 7, `drush en` typically will download and enable required modules automatically. But other kinds of libraries, like jQuery libraries, won't get installed automatically for you. In this kind of case, you definitely want to see if the module has a README file.  And for Views Slideshow, indeed it does.

From README.txt:

```
Installation
=============

1) Assure that you are using Views 3.x. http://drupal.org/project/views
2) Upload/install the Libraries API module. http://drupal.org/project/libraries
3) Upload/install the ctools library. http://drupal.org/project/ctools
4) Create a sites/all/libraries directory on your server.
5) Create a directory within sites/all/libraries named jquery.cycle.
6) Locate/download the jQuery cycle plugin. http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle
7) Upload/install the jQuery cycle plugin: place it inside the jquery.cycle
   directory.
8) Enable the Views slideshow and Views Slideshow: Cycle modules
9) You should now see the new views style option called "Slideshow"
```

These aren't the simplest instructions, but at least they're clear.

The good news is that in Drupal 8, drush uses the Composer installation system, and this kind of requirement will get auto-installed for you. But for Drupal 7, sometimes you'll need to track down the manual instructions.

Comment: Can I use composer with drupal 7?

Comment: You can, using the Composer Manager module.  I do this a lot with Drupal 7.  But that assumes that the Views Slideshow module (or whatever module has the dependencies) defines itself to composer (using a composer.json file).  My sense is that it doesn't.